# Select n elements from hover event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to select n elements from the element recieving the hover event. Is this possible in CSS?

E.g. In the example below, could I write CSS to select the next 2 items from the item reciving the hover event?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-1 item"></div>
 <div class="col-md-1 item"></div>
 <div class="col-md-1 item"></div>
 <div class="col-md-1 item"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
.item:hover:nth-child(n + 2) {
    background-color: green; 
}
```

However this does not have the desired effect...

Thanks!

Comment: Is the number (next [x] items) fixed and is it a small number?

Comment: It is fixed and it will be a small number ( < 10)

Comment: Less than 10 is still a big number for the CSS only approach that I was thinking of :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the immediate sibling selector (`+`)

```
.item:hover + .item,
.item:hover + .item + .item {
    background-color: green; 
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPGoYw

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of but I don't know if this good considering the number could probably be upto 10.

Comment: It's not ideal but it works and it's JavaScript free.

Comment: I don't think you have alternatives using only CSS and I wouldn't use JS if the amount of siblings is fixed

Comment: I was looking for a logic like this: `.item:hover ~ .item:nth-child(-n+2) { background: green; }` But it won't work!